# Frame does not assign the constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, autolayout

I am trying to add the facebook button.

Since you cannot drag and drop facebook button from the interface builder, you need to do programatically.

I add a dummy button with no text and try to assign its constraints to facebook button.

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.frame = dummyButton.frame; // try to assign frame values to the facebook button
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

The following image shows dummy button constraints.

[image]

But it seems that it does not work based on what I see.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autolayout is [two step process](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox/),

1. Caclutions of frame based on constraints
2. Layout of views based on calculated frames.

Before a view appears, this two step process may happen multiple times, and hence, frames at viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear are not guaranteed to be the fames expected.

So the best place to update frames is when ever the view lays out its subviews.

hence this line,

```
loginButton.frame = dummyButton.frame
```

does not guarantee the expected frame.

To make sure you always have the latest update frames, you can update your frame in,

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `layoutSubviews`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    facebookLoginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:facebookLoginButton];
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    facebookLoginButton.frame = dummyButton.frame;
}
```

Or

You can use a dummy view instead of a button and add you Facebook button to fill the dummy view.

Comment: It works on iOS 10.1 but suprisingly it does not work on ios 8.3. Any idea?